# DIfference between ID2D1Bitmap and IWicBitmap

Tags: windows, directx, direct2d, wic

What is the differnce betweem ID2D1Bitmap and IWicBitmap
I have raw memory data and i wanted to create a bitmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WIC bitmap represents an image in system memory that can be in a [wide range of formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797(v=vs.85).aspx) (JPEG, PNG, BMP, etc.).  A D2D bitmap represents an image in GPU memory that is one of a handful of [hardware-accelerated fomats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173059(VS.85).aspx).

Assuming you want to draw the bitmap to the screen using D2D, and your raw memory data is in a format compatible with D2D, you should use [`ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371800(v=vs.85).aspx) directly.  If it is not a compatible format (e.g. it is a pointer to the raw data of a .png file), you will need to load it into an `IWicBitmap` and then use [`ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371797(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have 16 bi t grayscale image raw data and i want to draw lines on that.How should i proceed

Comment: Once you draw lines onto it what do you want to do with it?  Display it? Save it out to disk as another image file?

Comment: I want to save it back into memory

Comment: How can i create a render target which supports 16 bit

Comment: You should be able to use the `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_*` family of formats.  Choose `UNORM` if you want floating point values `0.0->1.0` to be mapped linearly to `0->65535`.